# How can I remove a canvas element when my component unmounts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have a component which keeps trying to resize (on window resize) a canvas element even when the component unmounts. Therefore, the error only happens after component unmounts and the screen is resized. Previously, I've used setInterval to draw a canvas since the canvas was showing dynamic data. From there, I could use clearInterval to stop drawing the canvas. In this case, I don't need setInterval, since the data on this canvas uploads very slowly. This is where the error happens...

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.circleOne(); //These functions draw the circle
   this.circleTwo();
   window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
     this.circleOne(); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
     this.circleTwo();
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the "resize" listener in [React's componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) method.

In order to do that, you need to have a reference to the listener (ie it cannot be an anonymous function).

For example, you could make the listener another class method, like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this)
    }

    onResize() {
        this.circleOne()
        this.circleTwo()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.onResize() // Call to trigger the first draws
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```